# Tilemill/openstreetmap-carto, how to remove unwanted road lines

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, cartocss

I am using Tilemill and the openstreetmap-carto style.
The latest versions of each.
I was curious to why these Center-lines are showing up in my highways and roads, and I am unable to get rid of them. It is making my basemaps look cluttered and sloppy. I can't completely eliminate the layers because they contain the road names and symbols.
 I narrowed it down to be in the #roads-text-ref and the #roads-text-name layers. I posted the CSS for that section below. The road centerlines I have mentioned are in the picture. I am at a loss as to how I might edit these sections to get rid of these.

[image: example]

```
     #roads-text-ref {
         [highway = 'motorway'][zoom >= 13] {
          shield-name: "[refs]";
          shield-size: 10;
          shield-fill: #fff;
          shield-placement: line;
          shield-file: url("symbols/shields/motorway_[width]x[height].svg");
          shield-spacing: 750;
          shield-min-distance: 30;
          shield-face-name: @bold-fonts;
          shield-clip: false;
  }
  [highway = 'trunk'][zoom >= 13] {
    shield-name: "[refs]";
    shield-size: 10;
    shield-fill: #fff;
    shield-placement: line;
    shield-file: url("symbols/shields/trunk_[width]x[height].svg");
    shield-spacing: 750;
    shield-min-distance: 30;
    shield-face-name: @bold-fonts;
    shield-clip: false;
  }

  [highway = 'primary'][zoom >= 13] {
    shield-name: "[refs]";
    shield-size: 10;
    shield-fill: #fff;
    shield-placement: line;
    shield-file: url("symbols/shields/primary_[width]x[height].svg");
    shield-spacing: 750;
    shield-min-distance: 30;
    shield-face-name: @bold-fonts;
    shield-clip: false;
  }

  [highway = 'secondary'][zoom >= 13] {
    shield-name: "[refs]";
    shield-size: 10;
    shield-fill: #fff;
    shield-placement: line;
    shield-file: url("symbols/shields/secondary_[width]x[height].svg");
    shield-spacing: 750;
    shield-min-distance: 30;
    shield-face-name: @bold-fonts;
    shield-clip: false;
  }

  [highway = 'tertiary'][zoom >= 13] {
    shield-name: "[refs]";
    shield-size: 10;
    shield-fill: #fff;
    shield-placement: line;
    shield-file: url("symbols/shields/tertiary_[width]x[height].svg");
    shield-spacing: 750;
    shield-min-distance: 30;
    shield-face-name: @bold-fonts;
    shield-clip: false;
  }

  [highway = 'unclassified'],
  [highway = 'residential'] {
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-name: "[refs]";
      text-size: 10;
      text-fill: #000;
      text-face-name: @bold-fonts;
      text-min-distance: 18;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
      text-spacing: 750;
      text-clip: false;
    }
  }

  [highway = 'runway'],
  [highway = 'taxiway'] {
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-name: "[refs]";
      text-size: 10;
      text-fill: #333;
      text-spacing: 750;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-min-distance: 18;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    }
  }
}

#roads-text-name {
  [highway = 'motorway'],
  [highway = 'trunk'],
  [highway = 'primary'] {
    [zoom >= 13] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 8;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      [tunnel = 'no'] {
        text-halo-radius: 1;
        [highway = 'motorway'] { text-halo-fill: @motorway-fill; }
        [highway = 'trunk'] { text-halo-fill: @trunk-fill; }
        [highway = 'primary'] { text-halo-fill: @primary-fill; }
      }
    }
    [zoom >= 14] {
      text-size: 9;
    }
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-size: 10;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
  [highway = 'secondary'] {
    [zoom >= 13] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 8;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: @secondary-fill;
    }
    [zoom >= 14] {
      text-size: 9;
    }
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-size: 10;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
  [highway = 'tertiary'],
  [highway = 'tertiary_link'] {
    [zoom >= 14] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 9;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: @tertiary-fill;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
  [highway = 'construction'] {
    [int_construction_minor = 'no'][zoom >= 13],
    [int_construction_minor = 'yes'][zoom >= 14] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 9;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
      [zoom >= 17] {
        text-size: 11;
      }
    }
  }
  [highway = 'residential'],
  [highway = 'unclassified'],
  [highway = 'road'] {
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 8;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      text-halo-fill: @residential-fill;
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
    }
    [zoom >= 16] {
      text-size: 9;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
      text-spacing: 400;
    }
  }

  [highway = 'raceway'],
  [highway = 'service'] {
    [zoom >= 16] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 9;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      [highway = 'raceway'] { text-halo-fill: @raceway-fill; }
      [highway = 'service'] { text-halo-fill: @service-fill; }
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }

  [highway = 'living_street'],
  [highway = 'pedestrian'] {
    [zoom >= 15] {
      text-name: "[name]";
      text-size: 8;
      text-fill: black;
      text-spacing: 300;
      text-clip: false;
      text-placement: line;
      text-halo-radius: 1;
      [highway = 'living_street'] { text-halo-fill: @living-street-fill; }
      [highway = 'pedestrian'] { text-halo-fill: @pedestrian-fill; }
      text-face-name: @book-fonts;
    }
    [zoom >= 16] {
      text-size: 9;
    }
    [zoom >= 17] {
      text-size: 11;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you considered [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) it [replaces CartoCSS](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/carto/) and allows more control of the [Road Labels](https://www.mapbox.com/data-platform/)

Comment: I did try Mapbox Studio, from what I saw there is not templates such as openstreetmap-carto created yet. I also want to run the mbtiles from my own server and not upload to the MabBox Cloud.

Comment: Fair enough - In this case I will be of zero help - I do not know CartoCSS very well myself.

Comment: Do these lines appear also when you save a picture with the export function?

Comment: I actually thought that might be the case and exported the mbtiles anyway just to test it out. It still had the lines in them. Would a picture be different?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it well enough for my needs by just manually overriding the styles on the "style.mss" document. It looks way more acceptable now.

```
 #roads-text-name {
[zoom >= 13]{
line-color:#FFFFFF;
 }
 }  
 #roads-text-ref {
[zoom >= 13]{
line-color:#FFFFFF;
  }
}
```

[image]